# How can I use the same jQuery function for multiple divs without repeating the code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a add/remove textfield feature wherein I want to implement a jQuery function to all the textfields in a div.
Can I use the same jQuery function for all the fields in the div or should I write different for each.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/11109/) can be got here. In the demo I have made it work for one input field, how can I make it work for the rest.

**HTML**

```
<div id="single">
    <div id="Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes" class="row">
         <h2><a id="addScnt" href="#">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>
        <label for="Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes">Grpz Welcome Notes</label>
        <input type="text" id="Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes" name="Ivrgroupzbase[grpzWelcomeNotes]" cols="50" rows="6">
    </div>

        <div id="p_scents" class="row">
         <h2><a id="addScnt" href="#">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>
        <label for="Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes">Grpz Welcome Notes</label>
        <input type="text" id="Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes" name="Ivrgroupzbase[grpzWelcomeNotes]" cols="50" rows="6">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are having duplicate `Id` fix that.

Comment: i noticed that the id `Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes` is not unique which is not valid.

Comment: @Bob You mean to say I have a different id right for all input text

Comment: if you want to target multiple elements you can use 'class' instead for that purpose.

Comment: For best practices and conform with standards you might want to start reading from here. http://goo.gl/oj9b3u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Drea/28h0L6eb/

**html**
changed id "addScnt" to class - you should avoid using same id multiple times

**js**

```
  $('.addScnt').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.row').append(createInput($('#Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes p').length + 1), '');
});
```

Comment: Hi Drea, how can I consider to pass the id of the input field in current div

Comment: sry I don't understand what you want to do.
First of, you should change your id's to be unique.

Comment: Instead of hardcoded values like #Ivrgroupzbase_grpzWelcomeNotes p, I need to pass id of that input field inside that create_input function as well

Comment: I did this var div_id=$(this).closest('.row').find('input:text').attr('id');

Comment: I get the id, when I pass it to createinput it gives me NaN

Comment: I've changed the fiddle, but you still have duplicate id-names.